# Determine position of pointer in text file

Tags: c++, pointers, text-files

Assuming i have a text file

```
ID       Name         A1      B1       C1     D1
1234567  Bob Persie   12.1    33.0     44.0   55.0
7654321  Tom Hard     12.2    13.0     31.0   3.0
```

I need to append the word:talking to the word: Tom so it will look like this

```
ID       Name         A1      B1       C1     D1
1234567  Bob Persie   12.1    33.0     44.0   55.0
7654321  Tomtalking Hard     12.2    13.0     31.0   3.0
```

I know i need to use the readt.seekp function to set the pointer to the position after the letter 'm' in the word: Tom.

I have trouble determing the position of the letter 'm'.

readt.seekp(position, ios::beg);

Answer (score 2):

You have to rewrite the whole file, you cannot just insert some text like you are used to from a text-editor, you can only overwrite existing content and append to the end of the file.

One possible solution might be to read line by line, massage the line, write line by line into a temporary file, and finally rename the temporary file to your original's file name.

For the massage, do a string-replace. So:

```
source = open(sourcename, read-only)
(temp, tempname) = tempfile(write-only)

for each line in source:
    line.replace("Tom", "Tomtalking")
    temp.write(line)

close(temp)
close(source)
rename(tempname, sourcename)
```

Comment: i have tried, i can insert text into the textfile. I just dont know how to decide the position

Comment: You can write in the middle of the file, yes, but you'll overwrite what's behind the position that you're writing to.

Comment: @jrok: That's what I meant with "insert", but I'll disambiguate.

Comment: I replied to @Computernerd's comment, didn't mean to bug you :)

Answer (score 1):

read the whole file line by line - into a vector of strings for example, do the appending you need and overwrite the file. This is a more common and simple way to do it than seekp.

Comment: use getline to read the file line by line, saving the lines into a vector, change the line you want and dump it back to the file.. its straight forward and easy.

Comment: Better to write-as-you-read: faster (no need to stock up on memory to keep the whole text in the vector), and also clearer (a tight loop reading, possibly translating, and writing). The vector would come in handy if you need to operate a lot on the data; for example, if you are writing a text editor... but there are better data-structures for that.